# Wakanda with Oracle database by ODBC

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oracle, wakanda

Wakanda is the JS framework where we can develop our full stack js app.
https://wakanda.github.io/.

Can somebody help me to connect wakanda with oracle database (for mysql they do have connector)?
There official docs does not have enough information about odbc way of connecting via wakanda.

Answer (score 0):

From [the Wakanda documentation](https://wakanda.github.io/doc/#/guide?section=main-data-external-odbc) (as of 2018-04-25):

> ## ODBC
>
> > This is an enterprise version feature only.
> >
> > Unlike the previous sections that are common to all connectors this one is specific to ODBC. For now the ODBC connector is designed for MSSQL usage. In the near future it may be modified to support other databases (Postgre, Progress...)
>
> The Wakanda/ODBC Connector Pro allows you to create a Wakanda application connected to an existing MS SQL Server database through ODBC and to use the MS SQL Server data as well as its data model (tables, columns) from the Wakanda application. With this configuration, you take advantage of the graphical and functional richness of the latest generation of Wakanda Web interfaces while benefit from a direct access to your existing data through ODBC.

It appears that answer in the documentation to your problem is that Oracle (or anything that is not MSSQL) via ODBC is not supported (but may come in the "near" future).

Comment: Yeah, I do have enterprise edition only. Is it possible to establish the connection via oracle odbc way without depending on Wakanda connector? Like oracle-nodes driver. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Wakanda does offer the connector for MySQL, please refer to the documentation below: https://wakanda.github.io/doc/#/guide?section=main-data-external-mysql

If you have the license for Wakanda Enterprise version, you will have access to MySQL connector now.

The ODBC connector,  like @MT0 has already answered, it is tested and supported with MSSQL database at the moment. But it seems promising since additional databases support is underway. I recommend you contact [Wakanda](https://wakanda.github.io/what-we-do.html#request-demo) directly and maybe they can make it available to based on your need.

Comment: Yeah, I do have enterprise edition only. Is it possible to establish the connection via oracle odbc way without depending on Wakanda connector? Like oracle-nodes driver. Is that possible?

Comment: I have not tried it. But you can probably use oracle-nodes drive in Wakanda Nodeworker: https://wakanda.github.io/doc/#/guide?section=main-workers-node.

Comment: Have tried, but it's not even accepting the nodejs-oracle node module package. When I am required oracle in my worker js file, Wakanda not able to recognize the package and its methods.

Comment: Please make sure the node module is placed in backedn/Node_modules on your server, and use requireNode() in your worker: https://wakanda.github.io/api-reference/interfaces/nodeworker.html

Comment: Ya, Was doing the same. var oracledb = requireNode('oracledb');
Also I am using Wakanda 1.1.3

Comment: Nodeworker is only available in Wakanda v2 and above. You will need to upgrade your solution to use Nodeworker.

Comment: I tried waf-sql module which helps me to connect with Wakanda (so we eradicated the Oracle plan). But when am trying to maintain both 4d and MySQL getting an issue. first of all Is it possible?

Comment: I think it's possible waf-sql is a SQL connector which does not create new data model like 4D Mobile.  They work differently and separately. I suggest posting the discussion about SQL and 4D in a new SO question